# Delaying evaluation of Hypothesis strategies for Django models

Tags: python, django, python-hypothesis

I have a Django model. Among other things it has a `ForeignKey` to `User`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.BooleanField()
    bar = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I have a method in my tests that generates me an appropriately shaped `User` - `generate_test_user()`

I want to write some tests with [Hypothesis](http://hypothesis.works/) to assert assorted properties about instances of my model.

My first implementation looked like this:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    @hypothesis.given(models(MyModel, bar=just(generate_test_user())))
    def test_my_model(self, mymodel):
        pass
```

However this fails because `generate_test_user` gets called at import time and thus tries to create a model before Django migrations etc. have run.

What's a good way to craft a strategy such that the right things get evaluated at the right times / delay evaluation of the `just` call / similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR I wanted `builds` not `just`

From `hypothesis.strategies`:

```
def just(value):
    """Return a strategy which only generates value.

    Note: value is not copied. Be wary of using mutable values.

    """
```

whereas (edited for brevity):

```
def builds(target, *args, **kwargs):
    """Generates values by drawing from ``args`` and ``kwargs`` and passing
    them to ``target`` in the appropriate argument position.

    e.g. ``builds(target, integers(), flag=booleans())`` would draw an
    integer ``i`` and a boolean ``b`` and call ``target(i, flag=b)``.
```

Thus my original

```
@hypothesis.given(models(MyModel, bar=just(generate_test_user())))
def test_my_model(self, mymodel):
    pass
```

became

```
@hypothesis.given(models(MyModel, bar=builds(generate_test_user)))
def test_my_model(self, mymodel):
    pass
```

and all was as I wanted, with `generate_test_user` called at exactly the right time, at each test run

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to [draw the strategy interactively](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#drawing-interactively-in-tests) rather than specifying it in `@given()`:

```
@given(data())
def test_my_model(self, data):
    mymodel = data.draw(models(MyModel, bar=just(generate_test_user())))
    # Run assertions on mymodel
```